# Como evitar duplicidade com link canonical?

Tags: html, seo

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a utilização do Link canonical.

O link Canonical é um elemento da tag `<link>` que visa diminuir a quantidade de URLs com conteúdo duplicado.

As vezes vemos algumas URLs com o mesmo conteúdo e sendo assim, a relevância daquela página se dispersa entre as demais, divide o pagerank, fazendo com que a URL principal perca relevância, como no exemplo abaixo, diferentes urls apontam para a mesma página.

Ex: `http://www.meusite.com.br/index.html` ou `http://meusite.com.br`

O link Canonical é setado desta forma:

Head da index do site:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.meusite.com.br" />
```

Head da página de contato:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.meusite.com.br/contato" />
```

Agora, a minha dúvida é a seguinte, redirecionamentos 301, via arquivo `.htaccess` são outra forma de fazer isto, ou complementam esta técnica?

Comment: Acredito que mesmo você fazendo a requisição o caminho ainda continua sendo o mesmo, independente da resposta, então creio que a melhor forma é usar o canonical, por que você estará especificando exatamente de que URL se trata.

Comment: Tente usar esta sintaxe: `<link rel="norel" href="URL CITADA" />`

Comment: Desculpe @Nathan130200, mas não compreendi o que quer dizer o atributo "norel".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um assunto controverso e que cria bastante confusão e debate, entendendo um pouco como os dois funcionam:

### Redirect 301

Informa para os motores de busca que a página não está mais naquele endereço e mudou-se  permanentemente para uma nova página. Informa aos motores para remover aquela página de seu índice e indexar a nova página. Este sempre foi o padrão para redirecionamento permanente de página, ele diz aos usuários que a página original não é mais relevante e que o conteúdo está na nova página.

**Problemas comum:** Se você não tem acesso ao lado servidor não é uma opção. Outra desvantagem é que motores de busca podem demorar um pouco mais para atingir a nova página. O uso incorreto também pode trazer problemas, quando por exemplo redirecionar todas as páginas de um site antigo para a página principal de um novo site, isto mina a relevância de todo o tráfego de busca e pode resultar em uma alta taxa de rejeição.

#### Quando usar 301

- Como padrão - este é o método preferido de redirecionamento
- Páginas que estão sendo permanentemente movidos ou substituídos
- Domínios que são permanentemente movido
- 404 páginas e conteúdo expirado (supondo que o conteúdo relevante ou
  uma página existe)

### Canonical

Informa para os motores de busca que existem versões da página, mais para manter o índice apenas da versão favorita. Informa que as outras versões estarão disponíveis para que as pessoas possam visitar, mas para que mantenha apenas o índice da página preferida. Embora usado incorretamente como alternativa ao 301 é uma abordagem completamente diferente. Ao contrário do 301 que envia fisicamente o usuário para a nova página, o canonical serve apenas para informar os motores de busca. Quando você tem páginas com conteúdos semelhantes ou muito parecidos é quando deve-se utilizar canonical, exemplo:

Você tem duas páginas para listar produtos de sua loja, uma lista produtos por ordem alfabética e a outro por preço e as duas possuem URLs diferentes, se manter assim, motores de busca podem indexar as duas. Se sua página preferida é a que ordena por preço, você coloca o canonical na página de ordem alfabética e informa que a de preços é a mais importante.

**Problemas comum:** É apenas uma sugestão, embora os motores levem em consideração, eles não são obrigados a seguir. O mau uso mais comum da tag é quando ele é implementado em páginas que não incluem uma grande percentagem do mesmo conteúdo da página canônica. A menos que eles contêm pedaço considerável de conteúdo duplicado, provavelmente não deve ser usado. Outro mau uso comum ocorre com múltiplas páginas relacionadas. Por exemplo, você escreveu um post no blog que foi divido em diversas páginas com URLs próprias, informar apenas a primeira página do post mesmo que as demais contenham conteúdo relevante, fará com que os motores de busca *nunca* indexem as demais.

#### Quando usar Canonical

- Quando 301 não pode ser implementado, ou demorar muito tempo
- Duplicar conteúdo, mas se pretende manter todas as páginas ativas
- As páginas dinâmicas com várias URLs de uma única página
- Considerações entre domínios onde ambos os sites são semelhantes, mas
  precisa permanecer ativo

**[FONTE *em Inglês*](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2288690/How-and-When-to-Use-301-Redirects-vs.-Canonical)**

Comment: É uma boa opção usar um link em cada página, para evitar duplicidade por causa do caminho completo? `ex: www.site.com/index.html` e `www.site.com` que apontam para a mesma página?

Comment: @MarceloAymone neste caso a página é a mesma, não vejo como utilizar canonical neste caso, agora se você tivesse `www.site.com/index.html` e `www.site.com/principal.html` com o mesmo conteúdo, mais a `index.html` fosse mais relevante, então você indicaria na página `principal.html`

Comment: Pois então, noutro projeto antigo que eu possuia, o google indicava como conteúdo duplicado, por haver 2 urls diferentes caindo no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: @MarceloAymone estranho que o Google entenda a mesmas página com o mesmo conteúdo como duas páginas distintas

Comment: Então, quebrei muito a cabeça até descobrir. Porque meu domínio respondia tanto com www e também sem www, parece que o objeto de requisição é diferente, mas no fim aponta pro mesmo local.

Comment: @MarceloAymone O domínio responde tanto com www quanto sem se estiver configurado o CNAME no DNS do servidor, veja https://support.google.com/a/answer/112037?hl=pt-BR

Comment: hum... mas aí foge ao meu escopo, como o servidor é terceirizado, não possuo este nível de acesso para reconfigurar, então o canonical seria uma opção?